# Does Dell e6430 have eSATAp?

Tags: laptop, sata

Does anybody know, if the Dell Latitude e6430 have eSATAp or eSATA (without the p)? Wanted to buy an eSATAp to SATA cable but don't know if my Laptop has eSATAp.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  A quick Google search found a [Cnet page](https://www.cnet.com/products/dell-latitude-e6430/) with a list of all of the ports on your computer.  [image]